# Is there any way to print values in log viewer panel from Beanshell post processor in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I was using JMeter in GUI mode for performance testing of some functions, and as the functional nature of the test increased, I got stuck. It would be easy if I could print the values of the variables Obtained from JDBC connection in log-viewer panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use log.warn("message ...") as viewer only displays messages with level > WARN